# Why Scala class depending on a java generic class fails with NoSuchMethodError in spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, generics, traits

- NOTE: I have simplified my code below to avoid unnecessary confusion.

I have a scala trait filter below:

```
trait Filter[T] extends Serializable {
    def evaluate(input: T): Boolean
}
```

I am using it in a class to filter an RDD of a special type:

```
class OtherThing(filter: Filter[String], tokens: RDD[String]){
    tokens.filter(t => {filter.evaluate(t)})
}
```

This works, however as soon as I replace the scala trait with a java interface, I get the NoSuchMethodError. My java interface looks like:

```
public interface Filter<T>  extends Serializable {
    scala.Boolean evaluate(T input);
}
```

And the error complains that there is no method to filter an Object. The error message looks like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: my.package.Filter.evaluate(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z